# The folder of the package I install doesn't show up in the doocuments

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

So I am doing it as part of my homework. We are asked to install the tm package for data mining. Then, my professor told us to go to "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\tm", create a file called "texts", and put the documents we download as part of the homework there

This is his instruction

[image]

However, when I go to my own win_library, I found no "tm" folder. I have already successfully installed the tm package in my R project and call it using library.

[image]

Is this an error? What should I do? Thank you so much.

Comment: You should have given the directory as `../win-library/4.1/tm/`. Maybe. We don’t really know where your library is located and you are one major version behind the current R.

Comment: Your professor is giving you **terrible** advice. You should absolutely not modify the package library manually, and, depending on your system setup, you may not be *able to* do this, because of file permissions. Either way, don't do that (outside of this homework assignment), and be aware that your professor might have other misconceptions about how R works.

Comment: @IRTFM … *minor* version. The major version, 4, is current.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I suppose you are correct regarding how the terms are used by R Core, but I was using "major" in the sense of the level of version that has an impact on the availability of CRAN pre-compiled packages and the potential for a version change to break package compatibility. I assumed I was addressing a less sophisticated audience than persons such as you who are more aware of the evolution of the R language, I was trying distinguish it from the lowest level of upgrade that has fewer compatibility implications.

Comment: @IRTFM For what it’s worth this is the *universal*, standardised terminology, not merely used by the core R developers. Deviating from it is therefore probably not a good idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well. in this case the exchange between us should at least educate the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of **R**, the location of the personal library was moved from `Documents` to `c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\R\win-library\`.

You can see which paths are used with:

```r
.libPaths()
```

You can also change the library path temporarily for your session or permanently using `libPaths()` or environment variables. Details are explained in the `?.libPaths`help page. I would not recommend to do so if you don't know exactly why.

Two additional notes:

- the new location is in a system folder that is normally hidden. It can be made visible by changing an explorer option.
- I don't understand why your professor recommends to save downloaded data into the `win_library` folder. The folder is "sort of temporary" and in some circumstances it can be a good idea to remove it.
- A good place to store data is indeed under `Documents`. I recommend my students to store their files there, e.g. under `Documents/r_course/lab01/` and so on.